# How to make a random button backcolor generator?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Im trying to make my Start button generate a Color in all of those 4 boxes marked on the top of the Picture. The Colors should not be the same. Its supposed to work like Lotto but with Colors instead of numbers. Can anyone please tell me whats wrong with my code?

[image: Picture]

And thats my code;

```
        }

        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttontest.BackColor = GetRandomColor();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Color RandomColor = GetRandomColor();
            buttontest.BackColor = GetRandomColor();
            buttontest.Refresh();
        }

        private Random random;

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Create a new instance of the random class
            random = new Random();
        }

        private Color GetRandomColor()
        {
            return Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255));
        }

        private void buttontest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            buttontest.BackColor = Color.Red;

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: i dont see you setting the background of a button anywhere.

Comment: `Color  RandomColor = GetRandomColor();` -> `yourButton.BackColor = GetRandomColor(); yourButton.Refresh();`

Comment: is the timer there because you want it to change everytime the timer ticks?

Comment: This code is incomplete, and your question is not clear.  Please update your post and explain what the actual problem is, or what is not working.

Comment: Still no setting of the color anywhere. Maybe that's your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is something like that:

```
Random random = new Random();

private Color GetRandomColor()
{
    return Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255));
}

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.BackColor = GetRandomColor();
    button2.BackColor = GetRandomColor();
    button3.BackColor = GetRandomColor();
    button4.BackColor = GetRandomColor();
}
```

But as I know the game MasterMind you want to have a specific set of colors. Then the code should be something like that:

```
List<Color> possibleColors = new List<Color>()
{
    Color.Red,
    Color.Green,
    Color.Gold,
    Color.Blue
};

private Color GetRandomColorOfList()
{
    return possibleColors[random.Next(0, possibleColors.Count)];
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.BackColor = GetRandomColorOfList();
    button2.BackColor = GetRandomColorOfList();
    button3.BackColor = GetRandomColorOfList();
    button4.BackColor = GetRandomColorOfList();
}
```

Comment: The original question had a constraint: `The Colors should not be the same`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list suggested by Michael Seidel above and shuffle it when the `Start` button is clicked using, for example, the Fisher-Yates algorithm implemented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp).

```
private static Random rng = new Random();  

public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}
List<Color> possibleColors = new List<Color>()
{
    Color.Red,
    Color.Green,
    Color.Gold,
    Color.Blue
};

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    possibleColors.Shuffle();
    button1.BackColor = possibleColors[0];
    button2.BackColor = possibleColors[1];
    button3.BackColor = possibleColors[2];
    button4.BackColor = possibleColors[3];
}
```